# How to make a matrix for ordered pairs in R?

Tags: r, matrix, cartesian-product

I want to make a matrix of ordered pairs in **R**, i.e. every cell in the matrix will contain the dot (a,b).
I have tried this code:

```
calc_z<-function(results1){
#INPUT: Paired scores table
#OUTPUT: z score of a hypergeometric distribution as indicated in figure 1
a <- nrow(results1)
b <- ncol(results1)
results2 <- matrix(nrow = a ,ncol = b)
for (j in 1:b) {
 for (i in seq(1, a-3, 2)){
  results2[i, j] <- c(results1[i, j], results1[i+1, j])
  results2[i+1, j] <- c(results1[i+1, j], results1[i+2, j])
 }
results2[a-1, j] <- c(results1[a-1, j], results1[a, j])
results2[a, j] <- c(results1[a, j], results1[1, j])
}
`
`in my work: a=10, b=99`
```

The function takes two nearby variables and bind them to a dot (a,b) (the last lines are for the last numbers). When I try to run the code, I get a message:

```
Error in results2[i, j] <- c(results1[i, j], results1[i + 1, j]) : number of 
items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

What is the problem and how to solve it?

addition:
[image: This is the data, I want to take every nearby games (1st and 2nd for example) and make them an ordered pair. I thought about summing but there is a difference between (0,1) and (1,0), so I need to leave it as an ordered pair.]

This is the data, I want to take every nearby games (1st and 2nd for example) and make them an ordered pair. I thought about summing but there is a difference between (0,1) and (1,0), so I need to leave it as an ordered pair.

Comment: You can't put two number in a single place in a matrix.  Can you post an example of what you expect the result to look like, as I don't understand the meaning of "bind them to a dot".

Comment: can you please use `dput()` to supply an example of what the `results1` matrix looks like? (probably a small subset would be most useful) that will make it easier for ppl to provide clear answers :p

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put two numbers in each cell you can do one of the following where we illustrate it for the 1,1 element of the matrix:

```
# test input
x <- y <- 3

# character
mat1 <- matrix(nrow = 4, ncol = 7)
mat1[1, 1] <- paste(x, y)

# complex
mat2 <- matrix(nrow = 4, ncol = 7)
mat2[1, 1] <- x + 1i * y

# list
mat3 <- matrix(list(), nrow = 4, ncol = 7)
mat3[[1, 1]] <- c(x, y)

# numeric - encode assuming we know that largest element is < 1000
# and all elements are nonnegative
mat4 <- matrix(nrow = 4, ncol = 7)
mat4[1, 1] <- 1000 * x + y
```

Answer (score -1):

You're going by columns, right? Make sure you install the dplyr package and try this:

```
output <- apply(results1, 2L, function(column) {
  lead1 <- dplyr::lead(column, 1L, default=NULL)
  pairs <- paste0("(", column[-length(column)], ",", lead1, ")")
  # return
  pairs
})
```